# Mermaid Flowchart Text Aligned

Tags: visual-studio-code, flowchart, mermaid

I am currently working with Mermaid in VSCode and am having trouble aligning the text within the created boxes. It seems that the text isn't centered, and even goes outside the box. When I use the same syntax in [the Mermaid Live Editor](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/edit/eyJjb2RlIjoiZ3JhcGggVERcblxuICAgIHN0YXJ0KFtleGFtcGxlXSkgLS0-IEJ7VW5kZXJzdGFuZCA8YnI-IFByb2JsZW19XG4gICAgQiAtLT4gQ1tEZWZpbmUgTWV0aG9kcyBmb3IgVGVzdGluZ10gJiBEW1JldmlldyBMaXRlcmF0dXJlIHdpdGggUHJvYmxlbV1cbiAgICBDICYgRCAtLT4gRVtUZXN0aW5nXVxuICAgIEUtLT5GW0ZpeCBQcm9ibGVtXSIsIm1lcm1haWQiOnsidGhlbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0In0sInVwZGF0ZUVkaXRvciI6ZmFsc2V9), everything seems to work fine, but the problem occurs in VSCode.

```
graph TD

    start([example]) --> B{Understand <br> Problem}
    B --> C[Define Methods for Testing] & D[Review Literature with Problem]
    C & D --> E[Testing]
    E-->F[Fix Problem]
```

I have Markdown Preview Mermaid Support, Mermaid Editor, Mermaid Markdown Syntax Highlighter, and Mermaid Preview installed in VSCode. I've also tried using `<center> some text </center>` but `<center>` seems to be deprecated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit late but were you doing this in a `.md` file? You could customize the css using `<style>` tags before the diagram and specify some CSS which would help maybe.

Answer (score -2):

try to use it as E[Testing].center

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).